# Why does undefined behave different than other variables?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm using Google Chrome 16.0.912.63 and have the following code:

```
__defineGetter__('x', function(){ 
    console.log('In Getter: x'); return 1; 
});

__defineGetter__('undefined', function(){ 
    console.log('In Getter: undefined'); return 2; 
});

console.log(x);
console.log(undefined);
```

The getter function for `x` is entered correctly, but the getter for undefined is never entered. The output logged to my console is:

```
In Getter: x
1
undefined
```

I was always under the impression that `undefined` behaves the same as any other global variable. I know that statements such as

```
undefined = 10;
undefined = null;
undefined = 'defined';
```

Are all valid, so what is different about `undefined` that makes it unable to have a getter (at least in my browser).

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/7JcQk/)

Comment: It does not work on jsFiddle, but it does work when pasting in the console.

Comment: @pimvdb: I'd wager that's because console-evaluated code is wrapped inside a `with(console)` block, and so it defines a property `console.undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't behave like any normal variable, it just pretends to, at least on Firefox and Chrome. Try it:

```
var x;
undefined = "Hello!";
x === undefined; // true; undefined doesn't change
```

It's more like a readonly property but doesn't throw an error when it's written to.

Comment: That seems like a fun way to introduce debugging frustration... =/ Oh, and +1 for answering a question I'd never thought to ask. =)

Comment: @pimvdb: Weird indeed! [I'm serious about the true thing though.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2463964/Capture.PNG) Which OS and version are you using?

Comment: Also false on my Chrome v. 16 on a Mac.

Comment: @pimvdb: I'm on Chrome Canary 18.x, so that might be it. FrederickCheung's (deleted) answer is probably correct.

Comment: Windows Vista (don't laugh), and Chrome 16. Edit: Works on Canary indeed, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `undefined` was specified unwritable in ECMAScript 5, so many browsers might still have it writable. And it doesn't act abnormally, as ES 5 made it possible for objects to have non-writable properties (undefined is a property of the global object).

Answer (score 2):

It seems `__defineGetter__` just silently fails. `Object.defineProperty` throws an error:

```
redefine_disallowed
```

when you call this on Chrome:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "undefined", {
    get: function() {
        return 2;
    }
});
```

On the other hand:

```
window.__defineGetter__("undefined", function() {
    return 2;
});

window.__lookupGetter__("undefined"); // undefined, so __defineGetter__ just ignored call
```

---

Why it works in Chrome's console:

When you define *and* get `undefined` in one go when pasting the code in the console, it works, because there are some functions behind the scenes being executed which use a `with` block referring to `console._commandLineAPI`:

```
if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console) {
    inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI = new CommandLineAPI(
        this._commandLineAPIImpl,
        isEvalOnCallFrame ? object : null
    );
    expression = "with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {\n" + expression + "\n}";
}
return evalFunction.call(object, expression);
```

So you're just defining `console._commandLineAPI.undefined`.

Another point is that it overwrites `console._commandLineAPI` (see above code), so it does not work if you define and get `undefined` as two commands, since the getter has been thrown away by the overwriting by the time you try to get `undefined`.

This, plus the fact that it does not overwrite `window.undefined`, is most probably why it works in the console.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Well, `__*etter__` methods were deprecated for a reason I suppose :) +1